# What do wave solutions to the Euler-Lagrange equation mean?

Tags: waves, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

Assuming $c = 1$, consider the standard Lagrangian density for a scalar field $\phi$ and a *stationary* particle at $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0)$ with coupling constant $g$:
$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\phi_t^2 - \phi_x^2 - \phi_y^2 - \phi_z^2\right) - g\phi \delta^3(x).$$
We obtain the Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$\phi_{tt} - \phi_{xx} - \phi_{yy} - \phi_{zz} = g\delta^3(x).$$
The solutions to this equation are waves. When I usually think of fields they are static fields that affect the motion of particles. But the solutions to the Euler-Lagrange equation changes with time.

Or from another context, I understand the math used to derive the picture of electric and magnetic waves propagating along an axis perpendicular to each other. But I'm not able to understand the relation between this and the idea of electromagnetic fields produced by charged particles.

1. Are these two completely different concepts? How come I think of them as static in one context and dynamic in another?
2. Assuming they are connected, what determines the equations of motion for a particle affected by the field, rather than the evolution of the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these two completely different concepts? How come I think of them as static in one context and dynamic in another?

They are the same concept. You might be able to find some intuition from the membrane on a drum head. You can think of a displacement field associated with the drum head that lives in two dimensions. The value of the field is the displacement of each small piece of the drum head in the $x-y$ plane from its equilibrium position. When you bang on the drum, waves propagate across the drum head -- these associated with dynamical, wave solutions of the drum head displacement field. On the other hand, if you take a drumstick and press it into the center of the drum head, you still cause non-zero static displacement.

In electromagnetism, an accelerating electric charge acts on the electromagnetic field like a drum stick banging against the drum head. The accelerating charge creates a disturbance in the field that propagates out from the charge in a wavelike manner. Meanwhile, a static charge acts like a drum stick pressing into the drum head. The charge causes a static displacement in the field from its ground state.

> Assuming they are connected, what determines the equations of motion for a particle affected by the field, rather than the evolution of the field?

You can think of [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) as describing the evolution of the field, and the [Lorentz force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) $\vec{F}=q\left(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times \vec{B}\right)$ along with Newton's second law $m\ddot{\vec{a}} = \vec{F}_{\rm net}$ as describing the evolution of a charged particle interacting with the electromagnetic field.